# if functional interface extends another interface is it still a functional interface?

Tags: java, functional-interface

Java 8 in Action book by Raoul-Gabriel Urma, Mario Fusco, and Alan Mycroft stats that:

```
public interface Adder{
    int add(int a, int b);
}
public interface SmartAdder extends Adder{
    int add(double a, double b);
}
```

> SmartAdder isn’t a functional interface because it specifies two
>   abstract methods called add (one is inherited from Adder).

In an other similar example in the book the following interface called as functional interface.

```
public interface ActionListener extends EventListener {
     void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e);
}
```

What makes the first example not functional interface compare to the second example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `SmartAdder` provides **two** method definitions (i.e. `add` is overloaded, not overridden):

- `int add(double a, double b);`, and
- `int add(int a, int b);` (from parent)

Conversely, `EventListener` is a marker interface, so `ActionListener` only provides one method definition, its own `actionPerformed`.

Comment: ahh. Thanks I overlooked the parameters types.

Comment: @codeme you're welcome :)

Answer (score 5):

`EventListener` is an empty interface, so `ActionListener` which extends it has just one method - `public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)`. Therefore it is a functional interface.

On the other hand, `SmartAdder` has two abstract methods (`int add(int a, int b)` and `int add(double a, double b)`), so it can't be a functional interface.